# Text Display Jumping Left-Right due to character width difference

Tags: basic4android

I am using an EditText to display text received from a serial port which is updated 10 times a second, it works fine but one of the lines of text has a character that alternates beyween a digit and a dash (-). Becuase the dash is narrower than the digit the rest of the line of text after this character jumps right-left as the digit and dash alternate.

How can I prevent this so either the digit or dash could be displayed without the rest of the line jumping?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use monospace font. You can either change it with the visual designer or by code:

```
EditText1.Typeface = Typeface.MONOSPACE
```

Visual designer:

[image: Visual designer:]

Comment: Thanks, easy when you know how. Is it possible to have different font sizes on different lines with the same EditText?

Comment: You can probably do it with the RichString library: [link](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/richstring.html) Note that you should accept the answer to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You then should probably use `monospace` font:

```
<EditText android:typeface="monospace" [rest of attributes] />
```